# Is there a way to re-run successful tests, from previous run, with google test?

Tags: googletest

Is there a gtest flag or any other way to re-run tests with google test that were previously successful ( and no change to any code).

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... why would you want to re-run that subset of tests?  If a developer runs only one test using `--gtest_filter`, would you want to run only that single test on a subsequent run?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t seem that there is a specific option for rerunning tests.

You could run the test collection and generate a report in [XML](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#generating-an-xml-report) or [JSON](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#generating-a-json-report) format. Then, you could parse the report, and create a `--gtest_filter=...` argument by joining the names of successful tests as a colon-separated string.

You could also imagine writing a custom test listener. This would need to write out successful test names to a file, and once again, you could write some simple code to generate the corresponding `--gtest_filter` argument.